# How check if some three column already exists?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I try to create universal rating system for several model.

For example it's method for List model:

```
    public function setRating(RatingRequest $request)
{
    $rating = Rating::firstOrCreate([
        'entity_id' => $request->entity_id,
        'entity_type' => Feed::class,
        'ip' => $request->ip,
        'rating' => $request->rating
    ]);

    if (!$rating->wasRecentlyCreated) {
        $feed = Feed::find($request->entity_id);
        $feed->update([
            'rating' => round(((($feed->rating * $feed->count_rating_votes) + $request->rating) / ++$feed->count_rating_votes) * 2) / 2,
            'count_rating_voted' => $feed->count_rating_votes,
        ]);
    }
}
```

How check If user with some IP already voted for some entity_type = 1 and entity_id = 1?

If no add record and re-calculate rating?

Comment: I don't see any code relating to an IP, can you show us that?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy it's API. I only validate IP in request.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table for entity votes and relate it to each user with user_id foreign key,in user model type:

```
public function votes()
{
return $this->hasMany(App\vote::class);
}
```

in vote model type:

```
public function user()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo(App\user::class);
    }
```

now you can access to every user vote with:

```
return user()->with('votes')->get();
```